# How to plot this integral function with infinity boundary?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, scipy

I'm trying to plot Marcum function which is integral of Gaussian function in a boundary.

This is the function:

```html
<a href="https://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=Q(y)=\int_{y}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})~dx" target="_blank"><img src="https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?Q(y)=\int_{y}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})~dx" title="Q(y)=\int_{y}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})~dx" /></a>
```

y is a float value which user must input. I've written the code to calculate this function at desired value. However, What I'm going to plot is something like this:

!https://ibb.co/SRMsfY3

Here is the code to calculate Q(y) value:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import scipy, numpy, math
from scipy import integrate


def integrand(x):
   Q_y = (1/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi)))*math.exp((-x**2)/2)
   return Q_y


y = input('y=')
ans, err = quad(integrand, float(y), math.inf)
print(ans)
```

I tried to plot it using following code:

```
x_data=np.arange(-20,20,0.1)    
z_data=np.arange(float(y),1000,1)

    ans, err = quad(integrand, float(y), math.inf)
    print(ans)

    for item in x_data:
        z_data[i]=integrand(x_data[i])[0]
        i+=1

    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(4,4))
    plt.plot(x_data,z_data,color= 'blue',linestyle='--', label=label1)
```

which returns following error:

```
 File "C:/Users/m.rafiee/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 59, in <module>
    z_data[i]=integrand(x_data[i])[0]

IndexError: index 400 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 400
```

**I also don't know how to add those annotations shown in Figure and hashed area in plotting.**

I'm very grateful for any help in advance.

Comment: Provide a runnable code with all the variables defined. What is `x_data`? Define everything people need to run your code. Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added x_data

Comment: `i` is not defined in the code you show here. But the error tells you that `i` is 400, which is too much for an array with 400 values (because the 400th value has index 399).

Comment: @Majid : You need to first know for yourself, what should be the input value  of `y`. Then you need to make sure that when you print `len(x_data)` and `len(z_data)`, you get the same number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectorize your function and plot:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import scipy as sc, numpy as np, math
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def integrand(x):
   Q_y = (1/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi)))*math.exp((-x**2)/2)
   return Q_y

func = np.vectorize(integrand)

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

y = input('y=')

y = float(y)

result = integrand(y)

x_user = np.arange(y, 3, 0.1)

ax.axvline(y, color='green', lw=2, alpha=0.5)

ax.fill_between(x_user, func(x_user), facecolor="none", hatch="/", edgecolor="red")

ax.annotate('Q({0})={1}'.format(y, round(result, 2)), xy=(0, result), xytext=(0, result))

ax.plot(x, func(x))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Would you please help me in the second part of my question, too. How can I add hatch and marker to this plot according to y value which is entered by a user? For instant, user enters 2, and I want the graph shows a vertical line on number 2 on x axis and make all right side area hatched.

Comment: Please look a my updated answer. It's not exactly the same as your example image, but I think you'll get the idea behind it.

Comment: Thanks alot. This is very similar to what I've expected. so appreciated. I have to reduce line size, shift annotaion and make hatched area a bit bigger.